# GZipStream with large files doesn't work well

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

I want to compress some very large `GML` files (1-10GB). I wrote a method for this, but it does not work well. If I decompress it using 7-zip for Windows (or something else), I get the file that looks bad in the end (it's not finished, XML is just not finished)... I don't see what I'm doing wrong...

```
private void CompressFile()
{
    string outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.ChangeExtension(_gmlPath, ".gz"));

    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
    using (var compressing = new GZipStream(File.OpenWrite(outputPath), CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(_gmlPath))
        {
            var bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                compressing.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[edit]**

Additional question: How can I specify/change the name of file, that is compressed inside `GZ`? It's name is the same as the input's one, but there is no `.gml` extention:S (there is in input)...

Comment: Regarding the additional question: If you change your code to `string outputPath = _gmlPath + ".gz"` then you get "foo.gml.gz" instead of "foo.gz" if the input is "foo.gml".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

reads between 1 and 65536 bytes, but

```
compressing.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

always writes 65536 bytes, so you're ending up with junk in the file if you read less than 65536 bytes.

*Solution:* Write only `bytesRead` many bytes.

```
compressing.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're meant to write only as many bytes as you've read in the current iteration, not the entire buffer length.

```
compressing.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to achive that goal